# Tar Error In First Compress With Command Sed And "Argument list too long" When I Set 100.000 Distance In Sed

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, tar

I'v 200.000 rows in file not_found_test1.txt

I'am running command as bellow, but getting error in first result

```
tar czvf /home/bukanadmin/test.tar.gz -T $(sed -n 1,10p /home/bukanadmin/not_found_test1.txt)
```

This is error what i got

```
tar:     RT @StCecilias_PE\: Sara McBay y10 finished an impressive 4th in the JG 75m hurdles final. Sara only took up the hurdles a few months ago! #dedicated #workshard: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:     By stcecilias_re on 11-May-2018 17\:49: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:     at http\://twitter.com/stcecilias_re/statuses/994892363523874816: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar:     : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
2018/05/2018-05-11/TWITTER.DATA_POST/abfeda55a6f5b9ad1622f5484c7452f1.txt
2018/05/2018-05-11/TWITTER.DATA_POST/73a38258c9e91110065c3973b90fc841.txt
2018/05/2018-05-11/TWITTER.DATA_POST/240ae384d7e1e1d2f5f4fa1f70e7f0e8.txt
2018/05/2018-05-11/TWITTER.DATA_POST/e5a6f6c8bccc3c1d0ed9f11eb543c0a2.txt
2018/05/2018-05-11/TWITTER.DATA_POST/23a051f72192affbe2e57e91df62e372.txt
2018/05/2018-05-11/TWITTER.DATA_POST/f629b60d212a04dc4d42695f348446f3.txt
2018/05/2018-05-11/TWITTER.DATA_POST/c7037ea6e3912496fc546b7135a763f3.txt
2018/05/2018-05-11/TWITTER.DATA_POST/93675eeb45dbd6385cbf37b0d9d39341.txt
2018/05/2018-05-11/TWITTER.DATA_POST/ded62f41db4a069bd4fd36e83661cdd2.txt
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

And when i remove Sed on command Tar, i got no issue

```
tar czvf /home/bukanadmin/test.tar.gz -T /home/bukanadmin/not_found_test1.txt
```

When i trying another command in Tar like command Head, i got same issue

Can someone help me and explain please

**NEW ISSUE :) **
Last issue is done

```
czvf /home/bukanadmin/test.tar.gz $(sed -n 1,10p /home/bukanadmin/not_found_test1.txt)
```

Now, i got error when i change my code to

```
czvf /home/bukanadmin/test.tar.gz $(sed -n 100000,200000p /home/bukanadmin/not_found_test1.txt)
```

This is error explain
    -bash: /usr/bin/tar: Argument list too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `-T` is meant to read the entire file, so trying to grab just the first ten lines won't work.

You can likely elimiate `-T` altogether and simply do:

```
tar czvf file.tar.gz $( sed -n 1,10p file )
```

...or using `head`...

```
tar czvf file.tar.gz $( head -10 file )
```

Comment: weww.. thx sir, but got new issue tar *czvf /home/bukanadmin/test.tar.gz $(sed -n 100000,200000p /home/bukanadmin/not_found_test1.txt)* i wanna catch 100.000, i do this for loop later. my issue know  _-bash: /usr/bin/tar: Argument list too long_

Comment: @FakhryanAlbar: In that case you'll probably want to do: `sed -n 100000,200000p file > tmpfile ; tar czvf file.tar.gz -T tmpfile`.